# How can I repeat each array element a number of times equal to the element's value?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2,5,1])
```

How can I get an array like this using numpy or pandas or list comprehension etc? (not using for loop)

```
[2,2,5,5,5,5,5,1]
```

Comment: Any particular reason the 5 is in there 4 times?

Comment: @user2357112 sorry, typo.

Comment: According to your title, n=2, not 5

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sorry for misinformation, I had also given the required output in the question, hope question is not confusing to pythonistas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
In [11]: a.repeat(a)
Out[11]: array([2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

...

np.fromiter(chain.from_iterable(([b]*b for b in a)), dtype=int)
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension:

```
np.concatenate([[b] * b for b in a])
#array([2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1])
```